# Detalhes do relatório não são exibidos

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasper

Montei um relatório no Jasper Studio 5.6.0, e importei o meu arquivo *.jrxml gerado para o IDE onde estou desenvolvendo, porém tudo que é colocado na sessão **"Details"** do relatório simplesmente não aparece, mesmo sendo apenas um texto simples e fixo fica em branco, porém na **"preview"** do jasper studio ele aparece normalmente configurei assim o relatório:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não faço ideia de o que pode estar causando isso, por exemplo, se eu coloco o conteúdo na aba **"Title"** tudo é exibido corretamente.

Comment: Antes de responder me esclareça umas coisas: o que você quer no details vem de uma query? Qual seu datasource?

Comment: Eu tentei com querys (E quando testei no preview do JasperStudio exibiu direitinho) e tentei colocar um Texto Estático (Que no preview também funcionou) mas quando vou gerar o relatório, o arquivo PDF exibe tudo menos o conteúdo da aba details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou mostrar como contruir um relatório JasperReports do zero, já que não se sabe qual é exatamente o problema.

### No JasperReport Studio 5.6.0:

Primeira coisa é definir o Data Adapter, clicando em "Data Adapters > Create New Data Adapter"

[image: Figura 1 - Data Adapters]

Neste exemplo vou usar o Database JDBC Connection, mas ai o desenvolvedor escolhe e preenche os dados. Deve-se testar a conexão e ver se retorna "Sucessful".

Em seguida você vai no DataSet and Query editor dialog:

[image: Figura 2 - DataSet and Query Editor dialog]

Selecione seu Data Adapter no canto superior esquerdo e cole sua query no lado direito. Veja se todos os campos aparecem no menu abaixo (Normalmente é automático). Isso ficará na aba "Fields".

[image: Figura 3 - Query Editor]

Voltando para o design do seu relatório (figura 2), na seção "Detail", os campos que serão recebidos do DB devem ser colocados em um TextField e sua expressão deve ter o seguinte formato: `$F{nomedocampo}` (Figura 4 - Lado direito), sendo a tag `$P{nomedocampo}` para parâmetros. Os parâmetros devem ser colocados pelo desenvolvedor antes da geração do relatório (inclusive no preview). Para criar um novo parâmetro vá no menu "Outline (campo inferior esquerdo) > Parameters > Create parameter". (Figura 4 - Lado esquerdo)

[image: Figura 4 - Parâmetros à esquerda e Expressão à direita]

Ao clicar em "Preview" para verificar se tudo é exibido corretamente seu arquivo .jasper será gerado automaticamente.

### No código Java:

```
// Gerando um relatório com parâmetros
HashMap params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("nomeParametro", inputDoParametro);

URL arquivo = getClass().getResource("/com/seuprograma/seupackage/relatorio.jasper");
JasperReport jreport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(arquivo);
JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport, params, JDBCconnection);

// Gerando o pdf
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jprint, file.getPath());
```

Relatório sem parâmetros:

```
URL arquivo = getClass().getResource("/com/seuprograma/seupackage/relatorio.jasper");
JasperReport jreport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(arquivo);
JasperPrint jprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport, null, JDBCconnection);

// Gerando o pdf
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jprint, file.getPath());
```

Este procedimento foi testado com um banco de dados SQLITE, usando o JDBC sqlite-jdbc-3.19.3, java 8 e jasperstudio 5.6.0/ireports 5.6.0. Libs usadas:

```
commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
commons-javaflow-20160505.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
itext-2.1.7.js6.jar
jasperreports-6.4.1.jar
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela sua resposta, funcionou como eu precisava

Comment: será que você consegue em ajudar nisso, as vezes quando executo meu processo na hora de gerar o relatório o seguinte erro é exibido nos logs: `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font '
   net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.ttf
   net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.svg
   net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.eot
   net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/pictonic/pictonic.woff
  ' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.` Porém as vezes simplesmente funciona normalmente

Comment: Quando se usa uma fonte que não é padrão o JasperReports recomenda que você adicione um Font Extension, basicamente colocar essa fonte em um .jar. Mais informações aqui: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension

Comment: Mas eu estou usando a fonte arial, essa não seria necessário adicionar pois é uma fonte nativa né?

Comment: Eu até tentei adicionar o arquivo da fonte arial no projeto do jasper mas mesmo assim o mesmo erro foi acusado< tem algo que eu precise fazer depois disso?

Comment: Poderia postar isso em outra pergunta? Pois eu precisaria ver seu código jrxml. Desse modo outras pessoas se beneficiariam de uma possível solução.

Comment: Descobri o que era, eu tinha dois *.jar (Jasperreport 5.1.0 | 5.6.0) juntos e eu achei em um fórum que isso pode ser causado devido a isso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795447/jasper-reports-font-error